# Remove empty text boxes from a continuous form, but display those with data

Tags: ms-access

My subform has text boxes for address data. There are two text boxes for addresses (`txtAddress1` and `txtAddress2`). These are stacked one on top of the other in the form. And on the next row there are text boxes for `City`, `ST`, and `ZIP`.

Not all address records have data in `Address2`. In those instances, I want `txtAddress2` to not be displayed for that record and I want the row with `City`, `ST` and `ZIP` text boxes to move up so as to be just below `txtAddress1`.

In other words, I don't want a blank row between `txtAddress1` and the `City-ST-ZIP` row when there isn't any data for `txtAddress2`. But I do want `txtAddress2` to appear for those records that do have data in the `Address2` field.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: This isn't possible. Changing properties of controls in the details sections on a continuous form (like the *Top* property) will affect all records (as there is only one definition of "the" details section). If you need a "cleaned" list of addresses, create a report. Also: How would a user add an address line 2 if that box wasn't visible?

Comment: The subject form is set as read-only. A command button on that form opens an editable form where all address lines are displayed for a user to add new data.. Your statement that changing properties of controls will affect all records has been my problem. I just thought that there might be a VBA way to get around it.